# How to index tensor with high dimensional tensor

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have two tensors `x` for values and `y` for indexing. x.shape and y.shape are the same except the last dimension.
For example:

```
x=torch.tensor([[1, 6, 7, 5, 6],
        [8, 6, 7, 8, 4],
        [2, 8, 3, 5, 6]])
# x.shape:(3,5)
y=torch.tensor([[1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 2]])
# y.shape:(3,2)
```

Is there a simple way to slice it `x[y]`so that the result is:

```
torch.tensor([6,7],[7,8],[3,3])
```

What if x and y are higher dimensional tensors:

```
x.shape=(a,b,c,d)
y.shape=(a,b,c,e)
# a, b, c, d, e are positive integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html?highlight=gather#torch.gather) does.

```
>> torch.gather(x, -1, y) # index along the last dimension
tensor([[6, 7],
        [7, 8],
        [3, 3]])
```

The exact same command works with your high-dimensional case as well.